# Count occurrences from object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im making an api call and sorting data that I wanted from it. The only problem is that I have to count the date existed.

Currently I have successfully displayed the data that I want. Which looks like this.

```
2017-06-09T17:49:49.975+12:00

2017-07-13T08:59:20.023+12:00

2017-05-29T14:17:18.148+12:00

2017-05-21T22:19:07.951+12:00

2017-06-09T13:59:50.464+12:00

2017-06-13T08:18:30.340+12:00

2017-07-27T12:41:17.423+12:00
```

Now I want to count how many has the same dates. Format would be something like,

```
{ date = 2017-06-09T17:49:49.975+12:00, count = 2, date = 2017-07-13T08:59:20.023+12:00, count = 1... and so on... }
```

I've tried few codes from here which didn't work for me.

Here's what I tried recently, 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gxyZXm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version of the solution.

<kbd>**Codepen Demo**</kbd>

**JS:**

```
console.clear();

var counters = [];
$.ajax({
  async: true,
  dataType: "json",
  url: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/n1cwx",
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (i, object) {  
      console.log(object.last_activity_at);
      if (!object.last_activity_at) return; 
      var count= 0;
      var arr = [];
      for (var key in data){
        var date1 = new Date(data[key].last_activity_at).setHours(0,0,0,0);
        var date2 = new Date(object.last_activity_at).setHours(0,0,0,0);
        if(date1 === date2){
          count += 1;
        }
      };
      $("body").append("<p>" + count + "</p>");
      console.log(count);
      console.log(arr);
     $("body").append("<p>" + object.last_activity_at + "</p>");

    });
  }
});
```

Comment: returning "2" only.

Comment: @LittleNinja only one date is repeating!!! So we are getting two....isn't that's what's needed

Comment: i was after counting all dates existent.

Comment: @LittleNinja can you explain your last comment in more detail, I am not getting you!!

Comment: for example, 
"2017-06-09T17:49:49.975+12:00 will return count = 2
then 2017-07-13T08:59:20.023+12:00 will return count = 1 and so on..." it needs to count all dates

Comment: @LittleNinja Updated my Codepen, as you can see in the HTML the result is as expected! `2017-07-13T08:59:20.023+12:00  

1`

Comment: this is exactly what im afterr! you're a genius! thank you so much!

Comment: Another question, would it be possible to store one date in one position. For example, if 2017-06-09 has 2 counts, instead of displaying the date and count 3 times, it will just display it once with count.

Comment: @LittleNinja Please raise a new question from next time, its takes effort for solving an issue, anyway can you check this codepen [here](https://codepen.io/kai1992cool/pen/ayejdN)

Comment: i think this answer should be accepted as correct one @LittleNinja

Comment: @VeshrajJoshi Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep inner loop to outside of loop  like below

```
 // initialize the counters outside of the loop
 var counters = [];
 $.each(data, function (i, object) {  
  if (!object.last_activity_at) return true;
  counters[object] =counters[object] ? counters[object] + 1 : 1;
 });
 // keep next loop out side because you will get multiple line of same date with different number
 // now returning the same kind of dates
  var keys = Object.keys(counters); 
  $(keys).each(function(index,key){
      $("body").append("<p> "+key+":" + counters[key] + "</p>");
  })
```

Comment: let me know whether this works for you or not .. if your problem fixed please accept as an correct answer

Comment: im having an error on codepen. it says "illegal continue statement"

Comment: hmm ... sorry I went with general convention.. actually in $.each `return true;` acts like continue .. i think putting loop outside should works for you ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your pen to work somewhat, here's the key thing I did.

**Count the occurrences of each timestamp**

```
   let keys = Object.keys(data)
    let dateCount = keys.reduce((acc, val) => {
      if (data[val].created_at in acc) {
        acc[data[val].created_at]++ 
      } else {
        acc[data[val].created_at] = 1
      }
      return acc
    }, {})
```

`dateCount` now has the amount of times each date appeared. From there, it's pretty simple. I create a `count` variable that grabs the count, or if it doesn't exist, set it to 0.

```
   $.each(data, function (i, object) {  
  if (!object.last_activity_at) return;

  const count = dateCount[object.last_activity_at] ? dateCount[object.last_activity_at] : 0

 $("body").append("<p>" + object.last_activity_at + " " + count + "</p>");
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brXLOM?editors=0010

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've tried your code, just another question, why is "2017-06-13T08:18:30.340+12:00" returns 1 too even tho is exists 1 time. Tried changing 0 to 1 at "const count = ...." . Cause some date exist 1 time and I need a 1 count for that, not 0. Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
var counts = {};
dateArray.forEach(function(x) {
    counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(counts);
```